# Complex numbers as roots of quadratic equation

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I'm trying to solve quadratic equation

$$l^{2} - (2\cos x)l + 1=0$$

so x's are
$$
l=\frac{2\cos x\pm\sqrt{4\cos^{2}x-4}}2
$$
I've checked the solution on online calculators and they say it's
$\cos x \pm i\sin x$.
So my question is how can I solve equation above to get these roots?

Comment: *Hint:* $\cos^2 x -1 = -\sin^2 x$

Comment: @MartinR so $$\frac{2\cos x\pm\sqrt{-4sin2x}}2$$ ? then its easily transforms to cosx +- isinx since square root of -4 is 2i, right?

Comment: @Vanconts yes $\sqrt{-4}=2i$. This is because for $a$ and $b$ $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ which follows from $(ab)^x=a^xb^x$.

Comment: Just a caution about @CyclotomicField's answer: $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ doesn't actually hold true in general for complex numbers, or even where $a$ and $b$ are negative. What is true, however, is $\pm\sqrt{ab} = \pm \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$, which is all you need here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing with what you have:
$$
\frac{2\cos x\pm\sqrt{4\cos^{2}x-4}}2 = \frac{2\cos x\pm\sqrt{-4\sin^{2} x}}2 \\= \frac{2 \cos x \pm 2i \sin(x)}{2} = \cos x \pm i \sin x \, .
$$

Or, without that detour:
$$
 l ^2 -(2\cos x) l+1 = l ^2 -(2\cos x) l+ \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x \\
 = (l-\cos x)^2 - (i\sin x)^2 
$$
is zero if and only if
$$
l - \cos x = \pm i \sin x 
\iff l = \cos x  \pm i \sin x
$$

Answer (score 0):

The roots can be found with the quadratic formula. Note for your quadratic, we have $a = 1, b= -2cos(x), c = 1$. This gives us the roots via the quadratic formula:
\begin{align}
\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} &= \frac{2cos(x) \pm \sqrt{4cos^2(x) - 4}}{2}\\
&= \frac{2cos(x) \pm 2\sqrt{cos^2(x) - 1}}{2}\\
&= cos(x) \pm \sqrt{cos^2(x) - 1}\\
&= cos(x) \pm \sqrt{-1(1 - cos^2(x))}\\
&= cos(x) \pm i\sqrt{1 - cos^2(x)}\\
&= cos(x) \pm i\sqrt{sin^2(x)}\\
&= cos(x) \pm i sin(x)\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$l^{2} - (2\cos x)l + 1=0 $$

$$  l=\frac{2\cos x\pm\sqrt{4\cos^{2}x-4}}2 $$

The discriminant is negative. So, simplifying ( The common factor 2 cancels in the numerator and denominator ) and the above $ \sqrt{-1}=i$ should occur in the complex roots, and as $ \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x =1,$ we have

$$ l= \cos x + i \sin x $$

The roots are in the complex plane, the parabola axis  *may* be plotted parallel to real x-axis with imaginary y-axis thus:
[image]